# To pay or To paying?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

In [Arnel's Everday English Youtube video](https://youtu.be/1zWuafmkCJ8?list=PLwpPxXnl1gFR4MRaG-0AWvRSyVMIholyd&t=485) there is the following exchange:

> A: The client is refusing to pay. She owes us 1500

> B: Maybe she'll agree to paying in installment

why does B is using "to paying" rather than "to pay" to answer A's question?

Comment: Arnel's Everday English Youtube video.

Comment: @JamesK [link](https://youtu.be/1zWuafmkCJ8?list=PLwpPxXnl1gFR4MRaG-0AWvRSyVMIholyd&t=485) it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"agree to pay" would be a normal way of expressing this.  (agree to pay in installments)

But it is grammatically valid to have "agree to (something)"  For example

> He agreed to a short lunch break.

The structure here is "Agree + prepositional phrase"

A prepostional phrase can also be formed from "to(preposition) + gerund/participle phrase".

Gerunds are verbs ending in -ing.

However the meaning is pretty much the same as "agree + to-infinitive"

Comment: I do find a slight difference. _Agree to (infinitive)_ is saying "yes, I will". _Agree to (gerund clause)_ is saying "Yes, I accept that plan, or course of action" - often with an implication of reluctance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's why paying is used in the second sentence:

- Maybe she'll agree to ||paying in installments.||

Using another form of this to clarify the structure:
Paying an installment is maybe something she'll agree to.

**paying is a gerund form of the verb that behaves like a noun.** Here, in fact, a noun phrase using the gerund.

The verb+ING + [direct object] is the subject of the sentence.

One can agree to paying some sum of money.
In this case, the **to** is not a to-infinitive.

Please note: It could also be said as: She agreed to pay in installments. But there, it is a to-infinitive.

She agrees to pay in installments. [to-infinitive, shows finality or purpose.
She agrees to paying in installments. [gerund, she agrees to performing that action.

You can agree to pay in installments and not be doing any paying at all at a particular time.

Answer (score 0):

“Paying” is the continuous form. Since there are instalments, the paint won’t be instantly, but over some range of time, therefore the continuous form.

(The difference is quite small, so nobody will take much notice if you say “I agree to pay in instalments”.)

Comment: You've got some gnarly spelling there, bro. [paying is not the continues form here as the continuous form requires an auxiliary verb.